# I added a ScrollView and it gave me an error

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I added ScrollView like this:

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="200dp" >     
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="- A Learning"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:textStyle="italic" />
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="- B Learning"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:textStyle="italic" />
```

There is < / ScrollView > up

And gave me this at the Graphical Layout: 
Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child, Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

Comment: Scrollview can have one direct child. Wrap your views inside a `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 2):

Put both `TextView` inside `LinearLayout`. `ScrollView` can have only one child. You are giving two here.

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="200dp" >   
   <LinearLayout  
    android:layout_width="match-parent"
    android:layout_height="match-parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="- A Learning"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="- B Learning"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `ScrollView` for a Layout, i.e `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` etc... So simply have the two `TextView`s inside such a Layout and put this layout inside the `ScrollView`. Then, as it wants, `ScrollView` will have only one direct child.